# How to decorate/overwrite a function independent of how it is imported?

Tags: python

I have the following problem. I want to decorate a specific function imported from a module. Like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure = decorator(plt.figure)
```

However, to do it this way, I need to know how the user is gonna import the specific function (the matplotlib figure function in this example). What I am looking for is way to decorate the function independently of how it is imported:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

decorate_figure_function() # This function shall decorate the figure-function independent of how it is imported
```

I hope you understand my question.

Context: I am trying to build a logger for matplotlib, which can monitor the figures

Comment: The object `Figure` is always gonna be the same no matter how it was imported, isn't it? And that should be the argument to your decorate function. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: It is the same object, yes. But when I want to decorate it, I have to assign it to something (like in the first example). I can't modify the object itself, or can I?

Comment: Ok, i have no idea what went wrong earlier, Just decorating `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` works perfectly fine for all versions. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function which takes a method as argument, it does not matter how it was imported. You can name the argument as you wish, within the function you can refer to it by that name.

It sounds to me that what you want to do is creating your own figure class. Just inherit from figure and add methods, constructors and so on of your own.

See an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_figure_class.html) for figure specifically. And [Python class syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) generally.